# asp.net send the response about 15 minute

Tags: asp.net

i want when the client send to my web page request,my web page get the request and active timer and wait about 15 minute and check client so connect and response the json string.
my server code is:

```
 string name, count;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = Request.QueryString["name"];
        count = Request.QueryString["count"];
        Timer1.Interval = 15000;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;



    }
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json=jss.Serialize("در خواست شما تایید شد");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(json);
            Response.End();


        }
        else
        {
            Response.End();

        }

    }
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Having a long timeout (such as 15 minutes) is not a good idea because your underlying TCP connection could be closed by routers between your server and your visitor. I suggest maybe 1 minute at the most, and ensure your client re-polls the server regularly in case it does get closed.

Comment: @Dai thanks,i want for example customer send my server a order and when the system manager accept the order,response to client:your order accepted.

Comment: You must call the server on client side using javascript to check for the emails. This code will not work ! The `Response` is not exist when you try to call it.

Comment: @Aristos thanks,how can i do this?

Comment: Also, application pools will be recycled by IIS meaning that in-memory state like a timer is lost when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment : " thanks,i want for example customer send my server a order and when the system manager accept the order,response to client:your order accepted"

You will need to include jQuery to do this bit.

As you have the name and count in the query string, which I take it will help you identify the customer (or change it to an order ID), then you can use the following on your .aspx page in a javascript block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function()
    {
       location.reload();
    }, (15 * 60 * 1000));  // (that's 15 mins that I couldn't be bothered to work out...)

});
```

Your server side code could then be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var name = Request.QueryString["name"];
    var count = Request.QueryString["count"];
    if(OrderAccepted(name, count))
    {
        // display message to user
    }
}

private bool OrderAccepted(string name, string count)
{
    // do what you need to do to find out if the order is accepted.
}
```

You may also want to try and have the javascript only run if the order is not accepted so that it doesn't keep running.  But a 15 min interval is a decent long period, and most people will close their browsers once they know the order is accepted.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you are trying to do through "only" server-side (compiled C#) code.

The problem is that you want the *client* to send a request every fifteen minutes - to get the latest JSON - but you are trying to tell the *server* to do that.

There are many better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do (ie, better than a fifteen-minute timer) but here is one way you can achieve that through JavaScript:

First, expose your server's API call (the call that gets the JSON).

Then, in a `script` node on the client (ie in a `script` tag in the HTML you send down), define the following function:

```
function refreshDataAndUpdatePage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your/url/to/the/action',
        success: function (data) {
             // use data JSON to update page.
             // then, call this function again recursively after a timeout of 15 minutes = 900 s = 900,000 ms
             setTimeout(refreshDataAndUpdatePage, 900000);
        }
}
```

And of course, call it somewhere.